# Installing npm in Linux Mint 18.3

Tags: npm, npm-install, linux-mint

I am trying to install `npm` using `sudo npm install -g npm` but I am getting below error.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to upgrade npm to the latest? remove the current install on the system first:

`sudo apt-get purge nodejs npm`

then follow instruction for the version you need here:
(https://github.com/nodesource/distributions#debinstall)

Comment: Thanks @runwuf. I need upgrade command also. I am suffering this problem for last 2 days. I am installing and uninstalling `node` and `npm` again and again. Thanks.

Comment: Can I use this command after applying your command `curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs` ?

Comment: Yes, I tried it on mint 17 and it works just fine 
    `npm -v
    5.6.0`